# OpenMP: Can't parallelize nested for loops

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to parallelize loop with inner loop within it. My Code looks like this:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for private(jb,ib) shared(n, Nb, lb, lastBlock, jj, W, WT) schedule(dynamic)   //private(ib, jb) shared(n, Nb, lb, lastBlock, jj, W, WT)       //parallel for loop with omp
    for(jb=0; jb<Nb; jb++)          
    {
            int lbh = (jb==Nb-1) ? lastBlock : lb;
            int ip = omp_get_thread_num();

            packWT(a, n, lb, s, jb, colNr, WT[ip], nr); //pack WWT[jb]      


            for(ib=jb; ib<Nb; ib++)
            {
                    int lbv = (ib==Nb-1) ? lastBlock : lb;

                    multBlock_2x4xk(a, n, jj + ib*lb, jj + jb*lb, W+ib*lb*lb, WT[ip], lb, lbv, lbh);    //MULT BLOCK - 2x4xK (W[jb]*W[ib])

            }
    }
```

I measure time which proc spent on calculating this loops. It is the same for few threads as for one thread. When I change clause

```
private(jb,ib)
```

for

```
private(jb)
```

Everything is being changed. I mean for few threads proc is calculating faster than for one thread. What is the problem?

Comment: There's not much to go on here -- what's packWT, multBlock, a, etc? -- but you definitely need that ib to be private, or else threads will be overwriting the same loop index.   The reason it's faster without the private(ib) is probably that many ib's are skipped without it...

Comment: indeed, without private(ib) I get wrong results.. Still don't know why time is the same for many threads and one thread...

Comment: There's lots of reasons that could be, but none of us will be able to tell you anything without more information.

Comment: I have already checked that that doesn't depends on that functions winthin loops.

Comment: It seems on depends on compilator... The same code runs under windows in visual studio but on mac and linux with gcc it isn't good. I compile this with command: g++ -O0 -fopenmp -msse2 ...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your inner for loops is not in canonical shape. Therefore openmp fails to parallelize the loops and no speedup can be achieved. The loops need to look like the following picture. Where start, idx and inc are not allowed to be changed during the parallel part of the code.
[image: canonical shape of for loops]

I think I identified your problem. You are calling these function:

```
  packWT(a, n, lb, s, jb, colNr, WT[ip], nr); packWT(a, n, lb, s, jb, colNr, WT[ip], nr);
  multBlock_2x4xk(a, n, jj + ib*lb, jj + jb*lb, W+ib*lb*lb, WT[ip], lb, lbv, lbh);
```

where one argument is the loop variable jb, as jb can be changed inside the function (depending on the function declaration), the compiler decides not to parallelize the loop.
To avoid this copy your variable jb to a local variable and hand the local variable to the function.