# Why isn't this OpenMP parallel operation as fast as it could be?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a C program that must be implemented using OpenMP library. Its structure is:

```
for (t = 0; t < IT; ++t) {
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k, l) schedule(dynamic)
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                    for (l = 0; l < n; ++l) {
                        // calculations 0
                    }
                }

        // calculations 1
        }
    }

#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) schedule(dynamic)
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            // calculations 2
        }
    } 
}
```

This programs makes some calculations on a matrix.  Calculation 2 must be done after calculations 0 and 1 are done, because it make some modifications in the matrix.

The problem is that the speedup is very bad, i.e. the program is not scalable. The serial version for a given input runs in 79.46s.  When running with two threads it finishes in 41s giving an almost perfect speedup of 1.93 times, but when running 3 threads it finishes in 37.86s (with a speedup of only 2.1 times), and with 4 threads it takes 34.104s (with a speedup of only 2.3 times).

Why is this not scalable?

PS. I have an Intel i5 430M with 4 cores.

Comment: How big are your matrices? Parallelism over small data sets will probably end up having greater overhead than serial operations.  It takes time to set up and run threads, assuming they're not running already.

Comment: Perhaps this will not solve your problem, but generally, avoid declaring variables "private" in the pragma if you can. C since C99 (and OpenMp since a bit shorter) allow you to declare the `for`-loop constants inside the `for`-statement. Generally make it clear to your compiler that your loop variables and bounds can't change behind its back.

Comment: @KenoguLabz the matrix is 100x100.

Comment: Also, this may be appropriate to your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7910495/1708941

Comment: @KenoguLabz here is the loop code https://gist.github.com/4002876

Comment: Ooh, those `critical`s in "calculations 2" are probably hurting you.  I'd suggest trying the following, in order(1) time both loops separately and see how they each do and see where the problem is  (2) replace the criticals in the second section with reductions ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Reduction ).  (3) make it one parallel section with each set of calculations a separate omp for.  (Omp for, by default, have a barrier at the end, so they won't get to the second calculation before everyone's done the first), and (4) try using the collapse directive to flatten those loops.

Comment: `dynamic` scheduling is expensive and it adds a significant overhead that grows with the number of threads. It's better to use `static` if all calculations take the same amount of time. Besides you can merge both `parallel` regions into one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not so scalable because you have Intel Core I5. Intel Core I5 has 2 Cores and 4 Threads, so only 2 real cores, not 4. ( This type of processor uses the technology of Hyper-Threading )

The difference between a processor with 2 cores and 2 threads (e.g. Dual Core, Core 2 Duo, Core I3) and your Core I5 (which has 2 cores and 4 threads and uses Hyper-Threading to act like a quad-core processor) is that the boost in performance of your Hyper-Threaded Core I5 **CAN** be up to 30%. But you cannot compare your Hyper-Threaded Core I5 with a Core I7 (which has 4 cores and 4 threads).

Comment: Sure enough, 430m is dual core ( http://ark.intel.com/products/43537/Intel-Core-i5-430M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_26-GHz ) although some of the newer Core i5s are quad core ( http://ark.intel.com/search/advanced/?s=t&FamilyText=3rd%20Generation%20Intel%C2%AE%20Core%E2%84%A2%20i5%20Processors&CoreCountMin=4 )